# Why does python libs (eg imaplib) does not use logging but use sys.stderr.write?

Tags: python, logging

I'm not sure if it's because sys.stderr.write is faster.

Comment: gnibbler's answer is most probably correct; would you mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

imaplib is much older (it was in Python1.5.2) than the logging module (Python2.3), so perhaps noone has needed to update it to use logging yet